# VS Code Showing Irrelevant Pop-ups While Debugging

Tags: vscode-debugger

I'm facing a problem in VS Code which, if fact, is more of an annoyance than a problem. While debugging, as I hoover over macros, structs, variables, or pointer, a pop-up warning (from the bottom right corner) shows up instantly. I get two errors:

- A syntax error in expression, near 'variable_name'
- No symbol 'macro_name' in the current context

The actual output I get is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zykSZ.png).

But otherwise debugging a target device is done without issues. I just keep getting these errors and cannot tell what are they referring to, since nothing is actually wrong. Any ideas how to solve this issue or at least prevent these notifications from popping up?

I have tried few methods of disabling warnings and notifications but it looks like non of them were referring to this kind of notification. However I would generally prefer this problem to be solved without suppressing all notifications.

**EDIT:**

I need to point out that I have tried several different options of generating compiler symbols. Since I'm using the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler, I individually tried the following options: `-g`, `-ggdb`, `-gdwarf`, `-gstabs` (in addition to disabling all optimizations and leaving only `-O0`) but none of them affected the outcome. It seems the might be some issue with GDB and symbols being generated by the compiler.

Comment: possibly related? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5235, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4900, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10760